# need to save all the records at once to get url identifier in magento. Any efficient way or script available?

Tags: magento, csv

I have started work in magento last week, i have never worked before in magento. Recently i **imported more than 8,000** records in it using csv file. Now i can see all that records in magento admin panel so it's done successfully.

> **Problem:** But it is not displaying at frontend.
>   I found problem in **url identifiers**, to solve this problem i need to go in each record category and save it then url identifier showing and also displaying in frontend. So i have to do it for each record.
>   I think it will take more time and also i have to add 31,000 records more.

Do you have any suggestion to do it quickly? any **efficient way** available for me? can i use any script to save all record at once?
This question may have duplicate but it will pleasure if you give answer or suggestion to me.
Thank you.

Comment: please clear all cache from system=>chache and then re-index all from configuration=>index if Still problem persist then there might be some mistake in your csv fromat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just re-index all your indexes ?

Comment: it is taking 2 days for re-indexing. can i do only for that records which i have added recently ?